# Append new attribute with setAttribute()?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a div element and would like to append new style attributes to it.
I have tried to do it like this:

```
element.setAttribute('style', 'property: value');
```

And it works, but if that element already had styles applied, they will all get overwritten.

Lets say I have this situation:

HTML:

```
<div id="styled"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var styled = document.getElementById('styled');
styled.setAttribute('style', 'display: block');
```

This works, but if I need to append another style lets say:

```
styled.setAttribute('style', 'color: red');
```

I would then lose style added in previous setAttribute() method!

How can one append styles to elements with JavaScript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Well, if using `setAttribute` you could just take the previous value by [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) and concat them:

```
 element.setAttribute('style', element.getAttribute('style')+'; color: red');
```

However, that's not the best practise for most HTML attributes, which are usually reflected as a property and you could just do something like `element.className += " …"`. For inline styles in particular, you'd use the [`.style` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) that allows you to set and unset every single CSS property:

```
element.style.display = 'block';
element.style.color = 'red';
```

Comment: Using setAttribute for changing the style is a bad hack.

Comment: what? this is brilliant!!!!!!!! Yes simple, but darn smart!!! We 'hack' stuff when there is no other way. if someone has better way, should be posting it as answer, instead of simply round up a solution as a "hack"

Comment: @Ezeewei There *is* another way, even a better one, and it's mentioned right in the answer :-)

Comment: Actually for my specific case, this is the only solution work scalably. I know all the other ways but they are not what I want to do but actually your approach is what I never thought of! hehe

Answer (score 2):

Update the `style` object of the dom-node rather than using `setAttribute`:

```
document.getElementById("styled").style["color"] = "red";
```

More information: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp

Comment: Thanks Jo!  Great solution! Its works great for me to add another attribute to style without deleting the old values.

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding styles you can set them directly using the style attribute:

```
var foo = document.getElementById('foo');

foo.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
foo.style.width = '400px';
foo.style.height = '500px';
foo.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `setAttribute`, you're replacing the entire `style` attribute, so you lose any styles that are already there. You need to concatenate your addition to the old style.

```
oldStyle = styled.getAttribute('style');
styled.setAttribute('style', oldStyle + 'color: red;');
```

But it's simpler to use the sub-properties of the `style` property:

```
styled.style.color = 'red';
styled.style.display = 'block';
```

If you need to get the style name from a variable, you can use array notation:

```
styleName = 'color';
styleValue = 'red';
styled.style[styleName] = styleValue;
```