# Javascript setAttribute confusion

Tags: javascript, dom, css-grid

I was using the setAttribute method and noticed that if I use it consecutively, only the first time I use it the DOM elements changes, whereas the second time it doesn't work. And i don't understand why.

example, if i write this:

```
grid.setAttribute("style", `grid-template-rows:repeat(auto-fill,${width/size}px);`);
grid.setAttribute("style", `grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fill,${width/size}px);`);
```

only the grid-template-rows changes.

But if i put it all in one line like this:

```
grid.setAttribute("style", `grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fill,${width/size}px); grid-template-rows:repeat(auto-fill,${width/size}px);`);
```

then both values change, which gives the desired outcome.

Can anyone explain me why the first instance doesn't work?

Comment: when you use `setAttribute` it will always replays old one, it's not append !

Comment: You shouldn't use `setAttribute` to set styles anyway, instead use `grid.style.gridTemplateColumns = ...` -- or better still use classes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Append new attribute with setAttribute()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35190633/append-new-attribute-with-setattribute)

Comment: thank you so much guys for the help!! I got it now :)