# Why is my pause-resume functions not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css

my animation-play-state function is not working when I press the button to pause and resume the
animation. here's the link to my code: https://playcode.io/748688/

Comment: Please read [ask]. See [Something in my project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/4642212) — in short: no. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors, [edit] your question, provide a [mre] (this means, your _code must be in the question itself, as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/4642212)_), along with your _desired_ and _actual_ results, including all _errors_, demonstrate _your research and attempts_ and explain what precisely didn’t work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should not use setattribute directly on the style property, it will remove your previous move_to_right actions. Instead you can use following code, tested works.

```
/* Problem is here */
function pause() {
  div_color.style['animation-play-state']="paused";
}

/* Problem is here */
function resume() {
  div_color.style['animation-play-state']="running";
}
```

Also, you can refer to the following answer for reference.
[Append new attribute with setAttribute()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35190633/append-new-attribute-with-setattribute)

If this help you, kindly upvote and accept the answer.